# Angular js TextField validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an Angular js project, where I need to validate the data entered before submitting the form.

```
<select class="form-control" id="offerType" ng-model="addOffer.discount">
            <option value="Buy x get y free">Buy x get y free</option>
            <option value="Basket level offer - 100$ for 5">Basket level offer - 100$ for 5</option>
            <option value="Basket level offer - Product free">Basket level offer - Product free</option>
            <option value="Discount %">Discount %</option>
            <option value="Discount $">Discount $</option>
</select>    

<input type="text" required class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Discount Value" ng-model="addOffer.value">
```

This is my select box (which selects the type of offer that needs to be given) and TextField (which sets the value for the above selected offer).

When I select *Buy x get y free* then TextField should only accept values like X:Y and X should be greater than Y (e.g. 3:1) i.e. Colon between two integers.

And for rest of the options inputfield should accept only integers.
How to validate this textbox using Angular js?

I guess Directive should do the trick, but I'am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: as you are working on angularjs then you must have some knowledge about it. With that did you try anything? May be a little bit that shows your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have a few text fields that use different validation and `ng-show` when the corresponding option is selected. IMO having a text field that switches validation is too troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

You have switch validation based on option in single input box so we have set some constraints the check box should accept only integer. find below this

in ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" is used format pattern in input field.

```
 <div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" 
           ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.required">This field is required!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/1172/

Comment: thanks..your Demo works fine only for numbers, However I want to check if user has entered X:Y i.e. <number>:<number>